# Return primary id after Save in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to learn Laravel and struggling on how to return an id after I've inserted a row into the database.

Here is my current NotesController:

```
    public function store()
{
    $form = new NotesCreation($this->currentUser(), $this->params());
    if ($form->save()) {
        return Redirect::route('notes.edit', WHERE ID NEEDS TO GO)
            ->withSuccess('Note added successfully');
    } else {
        $this->view('create')
            ->withErrors($form->getErrors());
    }
}
```

I have tried to add $form->id, but it does not work. I get an Undefined property: NotesCreation::$id

This is my NotesCreation model:

```
    public function save()
{
    $success = false;

    if ($this->isValid()) {
        $this->user->notes()->save($this->notes);

        $success = (bool) $this->notes;
    }

    return $success;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I greatly appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Is `NotesCreation` your model? Edit your question and show us that class

Comment: I edited my question to show the NotesCreation model Save function

Comment: The problem is that this is not really a model. It's rather a repository. The `$this->notes` variable should contain the id afterwards so I suggest you make it public or write a method to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ->notes()->save() method must return the id:

```
$success = $this->user->notes()->save($this->notes);
return $success;
```

You can read about how to return last intested id in:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete or http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple way to get the last inserted id.

```
$leadmodel           = new Lead(); //mhy model name
$leadmodel->name     = 'name';
$leadmodel->save();
$lead_id = $leadmodel->id; //last inserted id
echo $lead_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create function

```
 $customer_id = Customer::create(array(
        'name' => $data->customer->name,
        'phone' => $data->customer->phone,
        'address' => $data->customer->address
    ))->id;
  dd($customer_id);
```

if you are using save than use this

```
$customer = new Customer();
        $customer->name = $data->customer->name;
        $customer->phone = $data->customer->phone;
        $customer->address = $data->customer->address;
        $customer->save();
        $customer_id = $customer->id;
        dd($customer_id);
```